# How do you create a Marker with a custom icon for google maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've been reading https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays for a while now and I can't seem to get a custom icon for my map working.

Here is my javascript:

```
var simplerweb = new google.maps.LatLng(55.977046,-3.197118);
var marker;
var map;

function initialize() {
    var myOpts = {
        center:    simplerweb,  
        zoom:      15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOpts);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:        map,
        draggable:  true,
        animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position:   simplerweb
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

Any pointers for a complete beginner with gmaps?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/how-do-you-create-a-marker-with-a-custom-icon-for-google-maps-api-v3

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    // draggable:true,
    // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002),
    icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png' // null = default icon
  });
```

> - **NOTE:** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons

Comment: http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png is just a dummy address, you should use a valid address to a valid image, also you have declared two times the same identical var "simplerweb" you can remove one of it

Comment: you means anywhere? yes the image can be hosted wherever you want!

Comment: I'm using my aws s3 bucket to get an image.@Luca
 but it's not working on ios. my project is on nativescript-angular. It says null, even if I assign a url.

Comment: @Heena Vora: i guess because in mobile development you can't include remote resource for security reason... most probably you should figure out a way to store the image locally.

Comment: For local images it works fine. The above code with URL as icon is not working for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      icon: 'http://imageshack.us/a/img826/9489/x1my.png',
      map: map
    });
```

---

from here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom

Answer (score 5):

Symbol You Want on Color You Want!

I was looking for this answer for days and here it is the right and easy way to create a custom marker:

'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=xxx%7c5680FC%7c000000&.png' where xxx is the text and 5680fc is the hexadecimal color code of the background and 000000 is the hexadecimal color code of the text.

Theses markers are totally dynamic and you can create whatever balloon icon you want. Just change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use "Overlayview" component as an alternative to Marker because you can use any html element inside "Overlayview" component. This is the trick I use to get around marker component limitations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33141054)