# change google marker in a wordpress template

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

hey guys i building a new website at the moment and i'm almost done, but there is one litle thing that i would like to chang.

its a property website with a google maps by each property and i would like to know how to change the google maps marker.  example link [property page](http://schmidtundpartner.eu/dt_properties/145/)

i found in a custom.js this line where i could change the zoom of it but there was no option to change the marker `if($("div#single-gmap").length ) {

```
    var $title = $("div#single-gmap").data("title");

    var $lat = $("div#single-gmap").data("lat");
        $lat = ( $.trim($lat).length > 0  ) ? $lat :  "-37.80544394934272";

    var $lng = $("div#single-gmap").data("lng");    
        $lng = ( $.trim($lng).length > 0 ) ? $lng : "144.964599609375";

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng($lat,$lng);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

From [How do you create a Marker with a custom icon for google maps API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376617/how-do-you-create-a-marker-with-a-custom-icon-for-google-maps-api-v3)

Add this after the mapOptions variable...

```
var marker;
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    // draggable:true,
    // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002),
    icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png' // null = default icon
  });
```

Just change the image path and the Longitude and Latitude based on your requirements.

Comment: u mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/4Luo3rpy/ ?

it didnt work,
here is the complete js of this file http://jsfiddle.net/a50ntdzv/

the line that i post is in line 273