# How to change the attributes of a marker on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a marker on google map

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 6,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
draggable: true,
title: 'Hello World!',
type: 'point'
icon : blue.png  
});
}
```

Now here if I want to change the Position of the Marker I can use

```
var lat=43.88632569, var lon=-83.53269589
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
marker.setPosition(position);
```

Is there any way through which I can change the Icon of the Existing Marker
like

```
marker.seticon(green.png);
```

Comment: Look at this posts answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376617/how-do-you-create-a-marker-with-a-custom-icon-for-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: What problem are you having changing the marker? A complete valid publicly available URL should work (or a hard coded SVG value or a 64bit encoded data URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors in you code (the URL should be a string and you are missing a comma between properties of the [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) object). A complete valid publicly available URL works for me:

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    type: 'point',
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
  });
  var blue = true;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
    if (blue) {
      marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png");
      blue = false;
    } else {
      marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png");
      blue = true;
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="btn" value="toggle color" type="button" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that whatever Attributes we assign to a Marker like icon, position, draggable, type etc  the can be changed at runtime like marker.setPosition();  marker.setIcon(); marker.setDraggable(); marker.setType();

Comment: There is a `.setOptions` method on [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)