# how to set custom marker for my current marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how to set custom marker for my current marker?

i tried this link but this doesn't work for me [How do you create a Marker with a custom icon for google maps API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376617/how-do-you-create-a-marker-with-a-custom-icon-for-google-maps-api-v3)

here my code

```
      var markers = [
       {
           "lat": '3.214608',
           "lng": '101.639114',
       },
       {
           "lat": '3.214790',
           "lng": '101.640928',
       }
       ];

       window.onload = function () {
           LoadMap();
       }

       function LoadMap() {
           var mapOptions = {
               center: { lat: 3.214608, lng: 101.639114},
               zoom: 16,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

           for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
               var data = markers[i];
               var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: myLatlng,
                   map: map,

               });
           }

       }
```

Comment: define "current" marker. one that is clicked?

Comment: mean the red default marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a global variable with a link to the image:

```
var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
```

To change the size / scale etc modify the code to include:

```
  var icon = {
    url: image,
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  }
```

When adding the marker use the *icon* variable, and assign to the *icon variable*

```
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: simplerweb,
    icon: icon// assign image here
  });
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cmjcs5eL/18/

Comment: what if i want to modify the icon size, what should i do?